# Listbox add-in with an overview of important workbooks and ability to open them

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I want to create a macro that I can share with co-workers with a UserForm Listbox containing an easy overview of all the important workbooks we have.

I'm just starting out with VBA Excel and have trouble figuring out how the program works. I've searched a lot on this issue but fail to find something that I can use. I suspect that the solution is quite straightforward.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

ListBox1.AddItem "WB1"
ListBox1.AddItem "WB2"
ListBox1.AddItem "WB3"

End Sub
```

Essentially, I just want a Userform with a Listbox of workbooks that I define. The workbooks are in different folder structures so I would need to set the path for each individual workbook.

The UserForm should have a command click box named "Open" that the user clicks on when having selected the workbook he or she wants to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open Workbooks via Userform Listbox**

In a very basic form you can use the following code in your UserForm module; of course you can/should rename the used controls to more *speaking* names (e.g. "OpenFileButton" instead of CommandButton1). Added the "Open file" functionality also to the double click Event.

```
Option Explicit                  ' declaration head of userform code module

Private Sub doOpenSelectedWB()
' Purpose: add open file functionality (called by CommandButton1 and Listbox1's double click event)
  With Me.ListBox1
     ' [1] Escape proc if no valid item
       If .ListIndex < 0 Or .ListCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
     ' [2] Get selected workbook name via list value (index 0 equals 1st column)
       Dim myFileName As String
       myFileName = .List(.ListIndex, 0)
     ' [3] Open existing workbooks via Workbooks.Open method
       If WBExists(myFileName) Then Workbooks.Open myFileName
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   doOpenSelectedWB
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   doOpenSelectedWB
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' Purpose: prefill listbox with array values
  Dim myWBArray()
  myWBArray = Array("C:\Users\Admin\documents\test.xlsx", "C:\Users\Admin\documents\test2.xlsx", "C:\Users\Nowhere\nonsens.xlsm")
  Me.ListBox1.List = myWBArray
End Sub
```

**Helper function `WBExists()` and formatting of command button**

```
Private Function WBExists(Fullname$, Optional ByVal Infotext$ = "File not found!") As Boolean
' Purpose: Check if workbook exists
  If Dir(Fullname) = vbNullString Then
      MsgBox "File " & Fullname & " not found!", vbExclamation, Infotext
  Else
      WBExists = True
  End If
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
' Purpose: name command button
  Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Open"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot! I get an error with the Workbooks.Open method (Compile Error: Method or data member not found). To compare, I have another .xlsm file where I don't get the error in Workbooks.Open. However, this file is from a post on some forum from 2008 and in a 97-2003 version of Excel. Do you have an idea of why I might get this error?

Comment: I found the solution to my comment here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21542778/Do-you-know-how-I-can-resolve-the-Compile-Error-Method-Or-Data-Member-Not-Found.html

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to name the workbooks items? Right now I have the folder structure links as the names of the list items, however I would like it to be only the name of the excel workbook. Any ideas?

Comment: Suggest to do some research at SO as this would be to broad to answer - there are numerous solutions here how to search folders and subfolders using e.g. the `Dir` function. A more sophisticated approach using  ADODB might give you some additional ideas (e.g.  [how to checking for most recent file in folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57775478/how-to-paste-csv-data-from-most-recent-folder).   :-)

Comment: I'm certainly no expert, however I don't believe what i'm trying to do is tremendously difficult. I have a list box with a set of X paths to my excel files, which I can open using your code above. They look something like this: C:\Users\UserName\Data\interest.xlsx, C:\Users\UserName\Data\Trades.xslx... Instead of having displayed the full file path in the listbox, I would rather have it say : Interest, Trades, and when you press it, you're opening the file by "accessing" the filepath

Comment: If I understand you correctly - i.e. same folder, same extensions, short file Name - , it's simple, indeed: a) shorten the array list in the *Initialize* event to `myWBArray = Array("Interest", "Trades", …)`, b) put the file name together in the *doOpenSelectedWB* procedure, e.g. `myFileName = "C:\Users\UserName\Data\" & .List(.ListIndex, 0) & ".xslx"`. Of course you might add further column data to the listbox list (e.g. col 0: short name - as proposed in comment, col 1. full name, col 2: e.g. file description) :-)